# How do I fix the error message "use of an internal package not allowed" when go getting a golang package?

Tags: go

I am using go 1.5.3. I ran this

```
go get -x github.com/goji/goji
```

and I am getting this error message:

```
git checkout master
package github.com/goji/goji
imports goji.io/internal: use of internal package not allowed
```

How do I resolve this ?

Comment: It's because the folder path you checked out into doesn't match the import paths in the source code. As a result the go compiler thinks you are trying to use internal things from some other repo.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/41060764/10245

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/46040715/10245

Comment: Make sure to set [go import path](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH). See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57953217/658497

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From that [goji issue 13](https://github.com/goji/goji/issues/13#issuecomment-171790915), the right command is:

```
go get goji.io
```

That page [`http://goji.io/`](http://goji.io/) has the `go-import` meta directive:

```
<meta name="go-import" content="goji.io git https://github.com/goji/goji">
```

That way, go does not consider `goji.io/internal` (see for instance [`router.go`](https://github.com/goji/goji/blob/fb52dfc61184d118950f39b11f2f3dcb14686fb8/router.go)) as trying to import internal package of a "third-party".
[This issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13755) illustrates the wrong internal import case:

> You are not allowed to import internal package (or its subpackages) of a third party repo.