# How to disable "use of internal package not allowed"

Tags: go

I have a go program that inspects a large repository, selects some packages of interest, and then generates a new main.go file that has:

```
import(
  _ (package of interest here)
  _ (another package of interest here)
  ...
)
func main() {...}
```

The main is interested in some values these packages set in their `init` method.

However some of these packages have (...)/internal/(...) paths and so I get `use of internal package not allowed` when trying to run the generated main.go.

Is there some compiler / linker / other flag that disables the `internal` path check?

Comment: No there is not. You'll either have to invoke the compiler "by hand" (`go tool compile`) ore move these packages.

Comment: Generally, if they are in an `/internal/` subdirectory, that means you're either using a library from before vendoring was added (Go 1.5/1.6), or _you're not supposed to use those packages_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internal packages in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571946/internal-packages-in-go)

Comment: Re invoke compiler "by hand", i have found no way of building it using the go build libraries as-is.

Comment: I have been able to do it by modifying the `cmd/go` pkg, removing all uses of  [disallowInternal](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/2ac32b6360b47e3e5bb87ad8cbc51c3d91467c85/src/cmd/go/internal/load/pkg.go#L591-L594)

Answer (score 18):

An import of a path containing the element “internal” disallowed if the importing code is outside the tree rooted at the parent of the “internal” directory. There is no mechanism for exceptions. In particular, by design, there is no ACL mechanism for allowing a whitelist of other packages to use an internal package.

[Proposal for the rule](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e8kOo3r51b2BWtTs_1uADIA5djfXhPT36s6eHVRIvaU/edit)