# Use of internal package not allowed on Windows 10 Go v1.12.5

Tags: windows, go

Yesterday I helped a colleague install go on his Windows 10 PC. We downloaded and installed the latest (v1.12.5) from golang.org. No errors were reported during the install.  We ran into problems trying to get and build a private project we're collaborating on.

The first problem was trying to use go get to fetch the project into the go/src tree. It prompted for his GitHub password and appeared to be downloading but failed with a complaint that the project contained no Go files. So we git cloned the project directly under C:\go\src. That succeeded, but attempting to build produces complaints about "use of internal package not allowed".

There are multiple prior reports of this error message on SO (e.g. [golang disable "use of internal package not allowed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060764/golang-disable-use-of-internal-package-not-allowed)) and as issues in golang/go (e.g. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26446) but most of the discussions explain the problem as having to do with attempts to import from internals of packages with repositories outside the project root.  *That's not the case here.*

The project is pure Go and all of the code in the repo builds successfully on OS-X and Linux.

**For the above reasons, I believe this question is not a duplicate.**

For reference, here is a much reduced view of the project directory installed under the go/src tree showing one of the files that produces the error when attempting to run go build. In this case the complaint references the internal/ace/ package as the disallowed import but the problem also occurs in other subdirectories (not shown) that import from other internal packages (also not shown.)

```
go
└── src
    ├── github.com
    │   ├── Michael-F-Ellis
    │   │   ├── pgcgo
    │   │   │   ├── internal
    │   │   │   │   ├── ace
    │   │   │   ├── setacertc
    │   │   │   ├   ├── main.go
```

Here is the outline of setacertc/main.go:

```
// setacertc is intended to be run from an internet-connected host to
// set the real-time-clock on the ACE11.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "time"

    "github.com/Michael-F-Ellis/pgcgo/internal/ace"
)

func main() {
    // SNIP
}
```

I suspect the problem is somehow specific to a new installation and/or running Go under Windows.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: The rule is not "project root". The rule is that `internal` packages can only be imported from packages **rooted** at the parent of the internal folder.

Comment: Also, do not download and put packages into the `src` folder of the Go SDK (is this what your `c:\go\src` is?). Use `go get package/path/...` to get packages recursively, especially if there are no Go source files at the project root.

Comment: @izca, thanks. So is my example not consistent with the rule? `pgcgo` is the parent of both `internal` and `setacertc`.  I think the problem must be related to your second comment since builds succeed on other installations. I'll ask my colleague to try running `go get` on all the subdirectories of `pgcgo`.  BTW, `pgcgo` doesn't contain any go files so that's another indicator that your diagnosis is likely correct.  Would our first attempts to use `go get` have succeeded if there were a "junk.go" file in `pgcgo`?

Comment: Yes, your project structure indicated in the question conforms to the rule. Try to remove the project you cloned with git from `c:\go\src`. That is most likely the root of your Go SDK. You have to place your projects inside `GOPATH`. Either manual `git clone` (but into your `GOPATH/src`) or `go get github.com/Michael-F-Ellis/pgcgo/...` will do.

Comment: Agree with @icza, your project is supposed to be placed under GOPATH which is usually %HomePath%\go folder, like C:\Users\<user>\go, but not C:\go. Check out "go env" in the command line.

Comment: @SergeyNarozhnyy yes that's almost certainly the problem. I'm so used to linux where the go binaries are /usr/local/bin and GOPATH defaults to ~/go/ that I spaced out on the differences in a Windows environment. I also didn't know about using an ellipsis at the end of a `go get` path. That would probably have made my first attempt to get the project succeed and I wouldn't have cloned it into GOROOT.  I'm still waiting to hear from my colleague when he gets a chance to try this.