# Why get 'use of internal package not allowed' error when importing an internal package?

Tags: go

I'm running [go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) test codes for `eth` [package](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/eth).

When I run `go test .` under the `eth` directory, I get the following error :

> `eth/api.go:37:2: use of internal package not allowed`

37th line of eth/api.go is as follows : 
`"github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/internal/ethapi"`

From what I understand, this import should not be calling the error, as this file is within go-ethereum project directory.

Running the same test command on others' machine does not produce this error, so I suspect that there is something wrong with my go settings.

What would be the problem? Appreciate your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [golang disable "use of internal package not allowed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060764/golang-disable-use-of-internal-package-not-allowed)

Comment: @Flimzy I believe not, because the file api.go is certainly within "the tree rooted at the parent of the internal directory".

Comment: No, I don't think it is.  Your error says `eth/api.go`. This means your code is in a directory called `eth`, but it's trying to import from somewhere called `go-ethereum`.  Perhaps you just need to re-name your directory to adhere to Go's expectations.

Comment: What is the result of `go env` and what is the current working directory when you run `go test .`? I played around with a similar senario, and could not get it to produce that error as the result of any mistake I could think to try...

Comment: @MiloChristiansen @Flimzy Apologies. I just realized that I was trying to run the codes from a forked repository `github.com/zoonoo/go-ethereum`.

Comment: Which leads me to further question : Would I have to change all the import codes to actually run the forked repository?

Comment: Probably, but at this point you know at least as much as I do on the topic :) Anyway, you should probably write your findings up as a self answer, this seems like an odd enough issue that you could save someone some time someday.

Comment: @MiloChristiansen Will do. Thank you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go : 'use of internal package not allowed ' when running a Go project forked from a github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46860546/go-use-of-internal-package-not-allowed-when-running-a-go-project-forked-fro)