# Go : 'use of internal package not allowed ' when running a Go project forked from a GitHub repository

Tags: github, go

I'm getting used to Go, and trying to understand how it works.

So I'm trying to run the test code from my repository zoonoo/go-ethereum, forked from the original repository [ethereum/go-ethereum](https://www.github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum).

When I run `go test .` under the `eth` directory, I get the following error :

```
eth/api.go:37:2: use of internal package not allowed
```

37th line of eth/api.go is as follows :  `"github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/internal/ethapi"`

Does this mean when you fork a go repository, you have to change the path of all dependencies within the code to run the code?
Does Go package system support repository fork at all?

Comment: The problem with the existing answers for me is that I'm forking a library that I then in turn import into another project. If my project references my fork then a fresh checkout and `go get` will not know to hack the folder structure and as a result it won't build.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As illustrated in [another Go project](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/pull/3910/files):

> ### Cloning a fork
>
> If you wish to work with fork of InfluxDB, your own fork for example, you must still follow the directory structure above. But instead of cloning the main repo, instead clone your fork. Follow the steps below to work with a fork:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/gocodez
mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/influxdb
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/influxdb
git clone git@github.com:<username>/influxdb
```

> Retaining the directory structure $GOPATH/src/github.com/influxdb is necessary so that Go imports work correctly.

Replace InfluxDB name/URL by your project, and the same idea applies.

In your case, the GitHub fork is only there for you to push your contribution back to it, and to make Pull request from it.
It won't serve as a source for `go get` to work, since the packages wouldn't match your GitHub for repo URL.

Answer (score 5):

This is because **internal packages** in go can only be imported by packages in the same directory root. It's kind of like package private classes in java. If you want to edit the code without having to rename all package imports you need to maintain the same folder structure that the package expects so if `github.com/zoonoo/go-ethereum` is in your **$GOPATH** rename the directory to  `github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum` or create a symbolic link and work from the linked directory instead.