# Cannot get a fork of a repository to build due to importing internal packages

Tags: go

I have made a fork of a repository (specifically, [github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum)) and am trying to make sure that I can build the main application (`cmd/geth`) before developing on the fork. However, due to the upstream source importing internal packages, the build does not work in my fork.

I have tried this both using GOPATH and Go modules. In each case, when I try to run go install `github.com/<me>/go-ethereum/cmd/geth`) I get the following error:

```
cmd/geth/main.go:40:2: use of internal package github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/internal/debug not allowed
```

In the Go module approach, I have tried adding a replace directive to use my fork instead:

```
replace github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum => github.com/<me>/go-ethereum master
```

But this leads to the same error.

I am happy to provide more information (e.g., build output) if that would be helpful, but it seems like there is something straightforward that I am missing, rather than simply replacing all instances of `ethereum/go-ethereum/internal` with `<me>/go-ethereum/internal`.

Comment: Clone your fork to $GOPATH/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using forked package import in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323872/using-forked-package-import-in-go).

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem, though. That would also mean that anyone who clones my fork would *also* have to clone it to the ethereum directory, and it's hard to believe that there isn't a more canonical and portable way.

Comment: If you are creating a new package that you expect others to import, then you need to replace the old import paths (`github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum...`) with the import path of your new package (`github.com/yourUserId/go-ethereum...`). The internal import paths will work after this change.  My previous comments assumed that you are fixing bugs or doing some other work where there is no intent to create a new package.

Comment: It's true that replacing these would work, but this would then create hurdles when merging changes to the upstream repository. I'm fine with doing this, but it seems like there should be a cleaner solution in Go. Is that really not the case?

Comment: Follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323872/using-forked-package-import-in-go if your goal is to merge changes back to the upstream.

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer. The idea is to merge changes from the upstream repository to my fork. It's unlikely that changes in my fork will be merged back into the upstream repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you are forking you should change the import paths as well.

Answer (score 0):

By default, GOPATH is set to $HOME/gopath, and your repository source code is placed in $GOPATH/github.com/user/repo (or $GOPATH/bitbucket.org/user/repo).

When working on a forked repo, in order to import internal packages, the path of the original repo should be added to the [go import path](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH).

As an example, on Travis-CI, [my forked repo failed](https://github.com/onsi/ginkgo/issues/599) on the same problem (use of internal package not allowed). So I just set [go_import_path in travis.yml](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/go/#go-import-path) - and it passed.

Answer (score 0):

### Root of the Issue

It turns out this issue has nothing to do with Go modules. It is raised because importing from [`internal` folders is disallowed in Go if you aren't in the same tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060764/how-to-disable-use-of-internal-package-not-allowed).

### How to Solve It

The only way to fix this issue is to not use an import statement to the *source*'s `internal` folder, but instead replace it with an import statement to the *fork's*.

If you've already used a `replace` directive the way OP has, you do not need to change *any* other import statement - just the one that's giving you trouble.

### Walkthrough of the Solution

Suppose you have source `github.com/source/s` and you have made a fork `github.com/fork/f`, and you've cloned the fork locally before making changes.

The `go.mod` for the fork will look like

```
module github.com/source/s

go 1.11

require (
...
)
```

and assume the file that's throwing the `internal` error will look like

```
package main

import (
   "github.com/source/s/something"
   "github.com/source/s/internal/somethingelse"
)
...
```

Add a `replace` directive and change the `module` directive to mirror your fork:

```
module github.com/fork/f

go 1.11

replace github.com/source/s => github.com/fork/f

require (
...
)
```

Now run `go clean -modcache` (to clear any older modules already imported by this module) and run `go mod tidy`. This gets everything installed cleanly, which removes any other sources of possible issues.

Go to the folder containing the problematic file, and run `go install` (as the OP did). You will see an error:

```
main.go: use of internal package source/s/internal/somethingelse not allowed
```

Just replace the problematic file's contents with:

```
package main

import (
   "github.com/source/s/something"
   "github.com/fork/f/internal/somethingelse"
)
...
```

and rerun `go clean -modcache` and `go mod tidy`.

Now you should be able to run `go install` with no issues, *and* have `replace` work the way you want.

(Personally, this was a very frustrating issue for me to solve! I was working on modifying a fork of a core package in the Go ecosystem, and the sheer number of dependencies that would break if you tried changing import paths naively made me tear my hair out. I am now able to sleep peacefully at night knowing the answer to this question.)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing that correctly already, but need to run `go mod tidy` after adding the `replace`.

*For anyone trying to do that in 2022 (or later). Tested with go 1.17.*

```
replace github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum => github.com/<me>/go-ethereum master
```

Then run, `go mod tidy`, and it will automatically replace the master to a version+hash, like: `v1.0.0-0.20220709042708-bfee27c57c7c`.
Check this example:

`go.mod`

```
module mymodule.com/module_name

go 1.17

require (
    gorm.io/gorm v1.23.8
)

replace (
    gorm.io/driver/postgres v1.3.8 => github.com/rwrz/postgres v1.3.9-0.20220709042708-bfee27c57c7c
)
```

On this example above, I'm replacing an indirect dependency of `gorm` module with my own fork. This number `v1.3.9-0.20220709042708-bfee27c57c7c` was replaced by the `master` that I was using.