# What to do if I want to make changes to a forked repository only to find that I can not because the forked package import itself

Tags: go, github

Like [this github repository](https://github.com/rylio/ytdl/), I forked the repository and made some changes to the code. When I run it, my changes are not in effect because the original code imports itself. I could simply just change the import library to mine like "import github.com/brucewangno1/ytdl". But is there any other clean way to avoid this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using forked package import in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323872/using-forked-package-import-in-go)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with golang forks of a repo, try and work in the import path of the original repo, and update the tooling to use your forked repo.

What I mean is, if you have forked the project `github.com/rylio/ytdl/` to your own github account `github.com/brucewangno1/ytdl`

Then you might have a gopath such as:

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com
├── rylio
│   └── ytdl
└── brucewangno1
    └── ytdl
```

You should make changes in the directory `$GOPATH/src/github.com/rylio/ytdl`.

To add the changes to your forked repo, you can set another origin in git, inside your local clone of `rylio/ytdl`

```
git remote add fork git@github.brucewangno1/tydl.git
```

If you do not plan on merging changes back into the upstream repo, you can use tools such as `dep` to ensure that you pull your own fork of that project instead of the upstream one. Something like:

```
[[constraint]]
name = "github.com/c/d
source = "https://github.com/myusername/d.git"
```

Comment: Thanks. You are of great help!

Answer (score 5):

Another easy way is to use `go get` instead:

```
$ go get github.com/original/a_library
$ cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/original/a_library
$ git remote add my_origin https://github.com/myaccount/a_library
```

In your case it will be

```
$ go get github.com/rylio/ytdl
$ cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/rylio/ytdl
$ git remote add my_origin https://github.com/brucewangno1/ytdl
```

Once you are done with changes, commit them and push using below:

```
$ git push my_origin my_branch
```

Answer (score 3):

> This answer assumes that you forked repository
>   https://github.com/rylio/ytdl/ to https://github.com/brucewangno1/ytdl

You need to create directory named `rylio` in your `$GOPATH` and clone your fork into that directory.

```
mkdir $GOPATH/src/github.com/rylio

cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/rylio

git clone https://github.com/brucewangno1/ytdl
```

Now, you will not face any issues related to the imports.

Comment: How interesting! Thanks