# How to use a forked module, with versioned Go Modules (v1.11+, GO111MODULE=on)

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protoc, go-modules

I [forked](https://github.com/rynop/protoc-gen-twirp_typescript) a go module, and want to use the fork in my project that uses [versioned modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive) via `v1.12`.  My code is not inside my `GOPATH`.

My project's `go.mod`:

```golang
module github.com/me/myproj

go 1.12

require (   
    go.larrymyers.com/protoc-gen-twirp_typescript v0.0.0-20190605194555-ffbfe407b60f
)

replace go.larrymyers.com/protoc-gen-twirp_typescript => github.com/rynop/protoc-gen-twirp_typescript master
```

protoc-gen-twirp_typescript is a tool for `protoc`, so here is my `tools.go`:

```golang
// +build tools

package tools

import (
    // protocol buffer compiler plugins
    _ "github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go"
    _ "github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators/protoc-gen-govalidators"
    _ "github.com/twitchtv/twirp/protoc-gen-twirp"
    _ "github.com/rynop/protoc-gen-twirp_typescript"
)
```

When I run `go mod tidy` to download my dependencies, I get this error:

```
go: finding github.com/rynop/protoc-gen-twirp_typescript master
go: finding github.com/rynop/protoc-gen-twirp_typescript latest
go: github.com/rynop/protoc-gen-twirp_typescript@v0.0.0-20190618203538-a346b5d9c8fb: parsing go.mod: unexpected module path "go.larrymyers.com/protoc-gen-twirp_typescript"
```

Why am I getting this error? I thought the [replace](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive) directive in `go.mod` allows for the [forked modules go.mod](https://github.com/rynop/protoc-gen-twirp_typescript/blob/master/go.mod) to stay untouched.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have the following `replace`:

`replace go.larrymyers.com/protoc-gen-twirp_typescript => github.com/rynop/protoc-gen-twirp_typescript master`

which if I've followed, is effectively `replace originalname => forkname`

I think the issue is that you are importing using the name of the fork, rather than the original name:

```
import (
    // protocol buffer compiler plugins
    _ "github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go"
    _ "github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators/protoc-gen-govalidators"
    _ "github.com/twitchtv/twirp/protoc-gen-twirp"
    _ "github.com/rynop/protoc-gen-twirp_typescript"   <<<< PROBLEM, using fork name
)
```

The error message you see seems to be the `go` command complaining about that.

I suspect it would work if you used the original name in the import statement:

```
import (
    ...
    _ "go.larrymyers.com/protoc-gen-twirp_typescript"   <<<< original name
)
```

You should also run `go list -m all` to see the final selected versions, including it shows the outcome of any `replace` and `exclude` directives.

Comment: THANK YOU! I was so confused on why the readme seemed to state that the go dev team explicitly planned for this case. What a dumb error on my part.

Answer (score -10):

> How to use a forked module [?]

You cannot. A Github fork produces a unrelated package, most likely not even buildable.

Don't fork, clone. Then push to a different remote (which can be a fork).

Comment: If I clone and push isn't that same as fork? Are you sure you cannot? https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive seems to explicitly state my use case: "replace also allows the use of a forked dependency, such as..."

Comment: All depends on the Details. If you fork a project with single package that does not pin its import path and does not use reflection to get its import path then of course you can fork and use the fork without and Problem. A github fork creates a new Package and is a Bad idea.

Comment: I'm a golang noob, but I think your comments are true in the "old" non-versioned go module way (when all code is within `GOPATH`), which is covered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323872/using-forked-package-import-in-go With new go module support (v1.11+) I'm pretty sure this pain-point has been addressed.

Comment: You are right. `replace` is only meant for local development, and have no effect outside of your own module (aka external tools like one in Q) . Details @ https://github.com/golang/go/issues/30354