# Undefined import from a separate package that is part of the same project

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, importerror

Here is the structure of a project/repo on GitHub:

```
|-grpc_definitions
|--v0
|---myservice.pb.go
|---myservice.proto
|-api
```

I forked the project and added some things locally; here is the new structure:

```
|-grpc_definitions
|--v0
|---myservice.pb.go
|---myservice.proto
|---new_service.pb.go
|---new_service.proto
|-api
|--myservice.go
```

In `api/myservice.go` I import the grpc definitions:

```golang
package api

import grpc_definitions_v0 "github.com/<username>/<repo>/grpc_definitions/v0"

var s grpc_definitions_v0.NewServiceServer // this line does not compile

var ss grpc_definitions_v0.ServiceServer // this line is fine
```

`go.mod` for `api`:

```golang
module github.com/<<owner>>/<<repo>>/api

go 1.14

require (
   github.com/<<owner>>/<<repo>>/grpc_definitions v0.0.0-20200723024905-6c479f56d135
...
)
```

If I look in `new_service.pb.go`, `NewServiceServer` is defined and it is part of the correct package. It imports everything that was already there just fine, only the stuff I added isn't imported properly.

If I go to the definition of `grpc_definitions_v0.ServiceServer` it looks like it's **importing a specific commit** of `grpc_definitions_v0` **instead of the local files**.

How do I get my code to import the files I added/changed?

EDIT: I tried to `go get` from a commit with my changes in it, but since I'm working on a fork of the repo it says: `module declares its path as: github.com/<<owner>>/<<repo>>/grpc_definitions but was required as: github.com/<<me>>/<<repo>>/grpc_definitions`

Comment: "it looks like it's importing a specific commit of grpc_definitions_v0 instead of the local files" -- what do you mean by this? Please show an example.

Comment: @Flimzy what I mean is that if I follow the "go to definition" link in my IDE for something that is correctly imported from `grpc_definitions_v0` then it takes me to a file outside my working project that does not have my changes (probably from the commit imported in the `go.mod` file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using `replace` for `go mod` in the terminal:

```sh
$ go mod edit -replace="github.com/<<owner>>/<<repo>>/grpc_definitions=/<<localpathtoclone>>/<<repo>>/grpc_definitions"
```

This points it to use the local files. See more at: [Using forked package import in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323872/using-forked-package-import-in-go)