# How to import a specific branch of forked repo into Go code

Tags: go, import

I faced with the following problem:

- I forked a repo, and made some modifications to it under new branch
- I create PR to upstream repo and it is not yet merged
- I want to adjust my Go codebase to import the specific branch of my forked repo

The problem:

- if the original repo is `github.com/user/pkg/v3` then the forked repo appears as `github.com/myusername/pkg`
- moreover, I made a new branch, e.g. `mybranch` where I made my fixes
- in the code where I used original repo I have an entry in my `go.mod` file as `github.com/user/pkg/v3` which I want to replace with specific branch of my forked repo

How should I correctly solve this issue?

What I see when I tried to change `go.mod` of my forked repo to be `github.com/myusername/pkg/v3` and then call `go get github.com/myusername/pkg@mybranch` is the following

```
go: github.com/myusername/pkg/v3@vxx-xx-xx: parsing go.mod:
    module declares its path as: github.com/user/pkg/v3
            but was required as: github.com/myusername/pkg/v3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using forked package import in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323872/using-forked-package-import-in-go)

Comment: Not really, since version and tags are involved. I tried to use replace and I got the following error:
```
replace ... v1.0.1-xxxx invalid: go.mod has post-v1 module path .. at revision xyz
```
So, the replace will require proper tagging and handling the versions. So far I didn't find correct way to do that and seeking for information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found required solution. The trick was to perform the following series of steps:

- fork original repo
- create new branch
- add modifications to the code
- push branch into forked repo
- tag this branch with version higher then original repo, e.g. if original repo had v3.1.1 then the tag I applied to my forked branch was v3.1.2
- go to code which depends on this package
- change `go.mod` file of my package to use `replace` directive and my new tag like this

```
replace github.com/user/pkg/v3 => github.com/myusername/pkg/v3 v3.1.2
```

Therefore, in order to use forked repo with new branch we must tag this branch in forked repo with version higher of the tag in upstream repo.